# How can I filter a table displayed using Expression Language in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Here's my code that I am using to display data from the database.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Book List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BookTracker" user="root" password="school" />

    <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from BookTrackerSystem;
</sql:query>

    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Book ID</th>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Book Author</th>
            <th>Book Genre</th>
            <th>Book Description</th>
            <th>Book Due Date</th>
            <th>Book Status</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${row.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookName}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookAuthor}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookGenres}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookDesc}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookDueDate}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookStatus}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.fullname}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do, using a simple textbox I want to be able to filter the table displayed using the code above, I believe I can do it using jQuery but is jQuery compatible with Expression language or is there any other method I can make use of?

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. JavaScript runs in the browser, long after the page has been generated using the EL at server-side. All it sees is the generated HTML page, and it can of course filter it, whether this HTML has been generated using JSP EL, PHP, or whatever you could imagine.

Comment: I was actually thinking of any Java based technology which I can make use of.

Comment: Then you will need to send a request containing the value entered in the textbox as parameter, execute the appropriate query, and regenerate the page (or the table onl, if you use AJAX). Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact almost nobody will support you in what you are doing :) .. I mean all is in JSP..

The exact answer is the following:

1. Add an html form with a textbox.
2. Add code that reads the textbox value as request.getParameter().
   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm
3. Add the value from (2) into your query `<sql:param value="..." />` and add `where` clause. Perhaps, you will need IF for two cases: a) filtering off - no text value and no `where` b) filtering on - text value exists and `where` used.

This will be a server-side processing (filtering) though.

If you want client-side filtering consider using DataTables http://www.datatables.net/